# connect to webcam from website without flash

Tags: php, webcam, photo

What are the ways I can allow users on my site to take a photo via their webcam to use as their profile photo? I saw on facebook they have this feature but there is no flash nor did i gt any popup to install anything. So i assume it is ajax/jquery based? I prefer not to use flash. Site is in PHP but ofcourse i have expertise in other languages which i can use to wrap around i needed.

Seeking an open source / free solution.

---edit: I saw this jquery plugin: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/
If they can do it in jquery/javascript then i assume it is possible?

Comment: Facebook webcam widget IS Flash.

Comment: I will check it again, did not get any flash error when i had flash disabled.

Comment: That JQuery plugins do also utilize Flash.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, neither HTML nor JavaScript have any support to access webcams -- you definitely need Flash or some other plugin to do this. And Facebook *does* use Flash -- try right-clicking the webcam upload area and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Mere PHP won't do the Job.

JavaScript doesn't have any support either. You have to resort to Flash or use some sort of plugins installed for the purpose.

Comment: see my edit above: I added a jquery link i just found. It uses javacript or am i mis-understanding the technology behind it...

Comment: I looked into it and it implicitly uses Flash. You will see some .swf files. The plugin allows you to access Webcam through Flash using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure on this but you can try using java applets..

Answer (score 0):

I think, spankwire webcam site has non-flash coding, It works in Ipad. I don't know which technology coding they are using to run in iPad. Make sure you don't visit that site in office/cafe. Because it is 18+ adult-site though.

Answer (score 0):

Well I actually can't say that it is jQuery, But it is javascript which can do so! After the release of HTML5, A library to get the user media was released. You may use `getUserMedia()` to do so. Good luck.